# vue 3 how to implement intersection observer for multiple element to create an active menu pointing to the element on the view port

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, intersection-observer

hello every one my goal is to make an active menu that shows what element in the view port

what i have so far and it work perfectly for one element

child template

```
<template>
  <div :ref="infoStepRef">
    <h3>{{ infoStepRef }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InfoStep",
  props: {
    infoStepRef: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  emits: ["on-step-intersection"],
  data: () => {
    return {
      isInfoStepIntersecting: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    isInfoStepIntersecting: function (value) {
      this.$emit("on-step-intersection", value);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const stepRef = this.$refs[this.infoStepRef];
    const handler = (entries) => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        this.isInfoStepIntersecting = true;
      } else {
        this.isInfoStepIntersecting = false;
      }
    };
    const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(handler);
    observer.observe(stepRef);
  },
};
</script>
```

parent template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="info-steps">
      <span :class="{ 'active': stepOne }">Span 1</span>
      
      I want to apply the 'active' class to the spans bellow if their coresponding child templates intersect with the viewport

      <!-- 
      <span>Span 2</span>
      <span>Span 3</span>
      <span>Span 4</span>
      <span>Span 5</span>
      -->
    </div>
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step One" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />

    Do I have to use the same prop (info-step-ref) and the same Emit from the child component (on-step-intersection)

    <!-- 
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step Two" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step Three" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step Four" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step Five" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />
    -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      stepOne: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleActiveStep(value) {
      this.stepOne = value;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.active {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
}
</style>
```

i did try this code

I want to apply the 'active' class to the spans if their coresponding child templates intersect with the viewport

Do I have to use the same prop (info-step-ref) and the same Emit from the child component (on-step-intersection)

Answer (score 0):

If I want to give you advice, please use vuex (or pinia for version 3).

But any way, if you insist to do it like that, there is no problem.

You have to add some ids to make InfoSteps unique. there:

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div :ref="infoStepRef">
    <h3>{{ infoStepRef }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InfoStep",
  props: {
    infoStepRef: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  emits: ["on-step-intersection"],
  data: () => {
    return {
      isInfoStepIntersecting: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    isInfoStepIntersecting: function (value) {
      this.$emit("on-step-intersection", { name: this.infoStepRef, value });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const stepRef = this.$refs[this.infoStepRef];
    const handler = (entries) => {
      this.isInfoStepIntersecting = entries[0].isIntersecting;
    };
    const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(handler);
    observer.observe(stepRef);
  },
};
</script>
```

and in parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="info-steps">
      <span :class="{ 'active': stepOne }">Span 1</span>
      <span :class="{ 'active': stepTwo }">Span 2</span>
      <!-- add more spans as needed -->
    </div>
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step One" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />
    <InfoStep info-step-ref="Step Two" @on-step-intersection="handleActiveStep" />
    <!-- add more InfoStep components as needed -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      stepOne: false,
      stepTwo: false,
      // add more steps as needed
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleActiveStep({ name, value }) {
      switch(name) {
        case "Step One":
          this.stepOne = value;
          break;
        case "Step Two":
          this.stepTwo = value;
          break;
        // handle more steps as needed
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.active {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
}
</style>
```

as you see, a switch satement used to update the data. also `handleActiveStep` is used to handle active InfoStep.

Hope Helps!

Comment: thank you so much Ali Bahrami